Create JSON formatted files in SQL Server with .txt extensions
In SQL Server, I need to create JSON formatted files with .txt extensions. Could anyone please advise as to how to do this?
I have yet to find a way. First, I select data SELECT * FROM [SQL Server table] for json AUTO, include_null_values. I tried saving this as a temp table but that did not work and I don't know how to save the results as a file in the SELECT statement I provided above.

SQL Server doesn't save data to text files, you need to use something else to retrieve that data from SQL Server and save it. What that is is up to you: C#, Powershell, Python, SSIS, Java, PHP, etc, etc, etc.
